# ionic2 - how to call app.component function

Tags: angular, output, ionic2

I am using `sidemenu` template and I want to call a function in `root page`( in my case, `app.component.ts`) from `child page`(page1.ts for example).

I tried to use `@output`:

**page1.ts**

```
@Output() triggerHeader = new EventEmitter();
...

this.triggerHeader.emit(true);///<-- trigger the action
```

then add the `(triggerHeader)` to the `app.html`:

```
<ion-header *ngIf="headered" (triggerHeader)="childTriggerHeader($event)">
```

and it did not work.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to do this is to create service and share it between two components(page1 and app.component) add `Subject` to service and fire-catch it. please read further -> http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/